# Docker Go SDK ContainerExecAttach returns timestamp

Tags: docker, go, timestamp

I am using docker Go SDK to execute cmd but I found timestamp was returned unexpected.

```
    ctx := context.Background()
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv, client.WithAPIVersionNegotiation())
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    config := types.ExecConfig{
        AttachStdin:  true,
        AttachStderr: true,
        AttachStdout: true,
        Cmd:          cmd,
    }

    IDResp, err := cli.ContainerExecCreate(ctx, ID, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    resp, err := cli.ContainerExecAttach(ctx, IDResp.ID, types.ExecStartCheck{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    text, _ := resp.Reader.ReadString('\n') 
    log.Print(text)
```

Output of `pwd` :

```
 go run .
/home/jovyan1:38:27  <- It seems this is a timestamp
```

How to remove this timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the logger is interfering.

Replace the last line `log.Print(text)` with `fmt.Printf("%s\n", text)`.

---

Update 1:

Actually, your `/home/jovyan1:38:27` fits the form of a go compile error message. You should try running `go build .` rather than `go run .` to make sure you program compiles first.

Comment: Yes, `fmt.Printf("%s\n", text)` this works, but `log.Printf("%s\n", text)` has the same output. I am confused.

Comment: That means your logger is adding those extra text.